# Generate an outgoing dataframe based on zero cross avg operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following input dataframe:

```
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'IDsensor': [1, 1, 4, 4, 4], 
                         'Sensor_SYS1_All': [54, 55, 75, 40, 58],
                         'Sensor_SYS2_All': [320, 315, 400, 300, 401]})

      print(df)

      # Output:
        IDsensor    Sensor_SYS1_All  Sensor_SYS2_All
          1               54              320
          1               55              315
          4               75              400
          4               40              300
          4               58              401
```

Based on this dataframe, I needed to group by IDsensor to calculate the average. So, I implemented the following code:

```
       df_Mean = df.groupby('IDsensor', as_index=False)[['Sensor_SYS1_All','Sensor_SYS2_All']].mean()

       df_Mean.rename(columns={'Sensor_SYS1_All': 'Sensor_SYS1_Mean',
                               'Sensor_SYS2_All': 'Sensor_SYS2_Mean',
                              }, inplace=True)
       print(df_Mean)

       # Output:
        IDsensor    Sensor_SYS1_Mean    Sensor_SYS2_Mean
             1          54.500000           317.5
             4          57.666667           367.0
```

Now I need to do the same process. This time, instead of calculating the average per group, I need to calculate the number of times that the sensor values ​​cross the average value.

Note: it is like the "zero crossing" operation, but instead of calculating the crossing of the zero value, it would be the average value.

I tried to make the following function:

```
         def zero_crossing_avg(array_data, var_mean):
              crossMean = np.sum((array_data[:-1] > var_mean) != (array_data[1:] > var_mean))

              return(crossMean)
```

Note: This function is working. The function returns the number of times it crosses the average value. 
However, it does not automatically and does not generate a response dataframe (as in the case of the average operation).

```
       # IDsensor = 1 for Sensor_SYS1_All
       zero_crossing_avg(np.array([54,55]), 54.500000)
       # Output: 1

       #  # IDsensor = 1 for Sensor_SYS2_All
       zero_crossing_avg(np.array([320,315]), 317.5)
       zero_crossing_avg(np.array([320,315]), 317.5)
       # Output: 1

       # IDsensor = 4 for Sensor_SYS1_All
       zero_crossing_avg(np.array([75,40, 58]), 57.666667)
       # Output: 2

       # IDsensor = 4 for Sensor_SYS2_All
       zero_crossing_avg(np.array([400,300, 401]), 367.0)
       # Output: 2
```

I would like you to generate this response dataframe automatically:

```
         IDsensor   Sensor_SYS1_Cross   Sensor_SYS2_Cross
             1              1                 1
             4              2                 2
```

Comment: Yes, I have already edited the code comment. Tks

Comment: Correct the error in the desired output dataframe. Thank you very much for your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and transform `mean` to transform mean values for columns in the dataframe except the grouper column  and then compare if dataframe values is greater than mean values , then groupby `IDsensor` column and take sum of the booleans:

```
out = (df.drop('IDsensor',1).gt(df.groupby('IDsensor').transform('mean'))
                              .groupby(df['IDsensor']).sum().astype(int))
out = out.rename(columns = lambda x: f"{x.rsplit('_',1)[0]}_Cross").reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

   IDsensor  Sensor_SYS1_Cross  Sensor_SYS2_Cross
0         1                  1                  1
1         4                  2                  2
```

You can see what transform does here:

```
print(df.groupby('IDsensor').transform('mean'))

    Sensor_SYS1_All  Sensor_SYS2_All
0        54.500000            317.5
1        54.500000            317.5
2        57.666667            367.0
3        57.666667            367.0
4        57.666667            367.0
```

**Note:** if you want this for specific 2 columns , replace `df.groupby('IDsensor').transform('mean')` with `df.groupby('IDsensor')[list_of_column_names].transform('mean')` and compare only those columns `df[list_of_column_names].gt(df.groupby....)` like below:

```
col_list = ['Sensor_SYS1_All','Sensor_SYS2_All']
out = (df[col_list].gt(df.groupby('IDsensor')[col_list].transform('mean'))
                              .groupby(df['IDsensor']).sum().astype(int))
out = out.rename(columns = lambda x: f"{x.rsplit('_',1)[0]}_Cross").reset_index()
```

Comment: I was unable to select specific columns. Can you put what the complete code would look like?

Comment: @JaneBorges Done edited the answer with the code below :) Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Worked perfectly. I have another question: in another code, I have the following columns: col_list = ['SENSOR_SYS_1,' SENSOR_SYS_2, 'SENSOR_SYS_7]. When I execute the code, when renaming, it loses the numbers 1, 2 and 7. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @JaneBorges then instead of using `out = out.rename(.....)` just use `out = out.add_suffix("_Cross")`

Comment: great! just one more question. Just like I averaged it at the beginning of the problem. I would like to know how to calculate the variance. You can help?

Comment: @JaneBorges i think you are looking for `df.groupby('IDsensor').transform('var')` instead of `df.groupby('IDsensor').transform('mean')`

Comment: great! Just one more question: I managed to group by min () and max(). But I don't know how to calculate the oscillation: do you know if you have a function ready?

Comment: @JaneBorges Unfortunately no idea on that , may be you can post a new question for that :)